# Restsharp.RestRequest.RemoveJsonBody()

Tags: c#, rest, web, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I can add to the JSON body by doing this:

```
_request.AddJsonBody(obj1);
_request.AddJsonBody(obj2);
```

How can I clear the body? There is no `RemoveJsonBody()` method or anything similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
_request.Parameters.Clear();
```

To clear all parameters from the request body.

OR

```
_request.Parameters.RemoveAt(1);
```

to remove an element at a specific index.

OR

you can get funky with it and remove just the RequestBody type and preserve the headers:

```
_request.Parameters.RemoveAll(x => x.Type == RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: But the parameters contain the headers as well as body objects. 
How can I just get rid of the body objects?

Comment: In RestSharp for dotnet core, clearing the parameters no longer clears the body! In dotnet core, the Body is modelled as a separate property, which needs an explicit set to null, to be cleared. I'm comparing latest restsharp-version as of this writing: 106.6.9 for full dotnet, vs 106.12.0 for dotnet core.